# Oracle 11g Select Distinct Not Unique

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I kinda lost with this simple query

Below is the query with date (**SERVICE_DATE**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID,
       SERVICE_DATE,
       GRAND_TOTAL,
       TYPE_INSERT,
       PAYMENT_ID
FROM   TBL_XXX
WHERE  USER_ID = 100
       AND PAYMENT_ID <> 0
ORDER  BY JOB_ID DESC;
```

And I got this result:

```
467 18/10/2012  16  Upload  527811
467 18/10/2012  16  Upload  527811
466 18/10/2012  4   Key-In  527806
465 18/10/2012  4   Key-In  527804
464 17/10/2012  24  Upload  527784
464 17/10/2012  24  Upload  527784
464 17/10/2012  24  Upload  527784
```

while this query without date (**SERVICE_DATE**)

```
SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID,
       GRAND_TOTAL,
       TYPE_INSERT,
       PAYMENT_ID
FROM   TBL_XXX
WHERE  USER_ID = 100
       AND PAYMENT_ID <> 0
ORDER  BY JOB_ID DESC;
```

Result:

```
467 16  Upload  527811
466 4   Key-In  527806
465 4   Key-In  527804
464 24  Upload  527784
```

what Im missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service_date is a date wich contains a time part, but your IDE present only the date part.

To see the detalis you may change the preferences of your IDE for the format of date or use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID,
       to_char(SERVICE_DATE,'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
       GRAND_TOTAL,
...
```

Comment: the data itself only contain date. no hours, minutes and seconds but i try to use the to_char(SERVICE_DATE,'yyyy-mon-dd') and its working! thx

Comment: i choose this answer because the resources less expensive

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this if it works, I think it has something to do with your `SERVICE_DATE` so I modified your query to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and windows function.

```
SELECT  JOB_ID,
        SERVICE_DATE,
        GRAND_TOTAL,
        TYPE_INSERT,
        PAYMENT_ID
FROM
    (
        SELECT JOB_ID,
               SERVICE_DATE,
               GRAND_TOTAL,
               TYPE_INSERT,
               PAYMENT_ID,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_ID 
                                  ORDER BY SERVICE_DATE DESC) rn
        FROM   TBL_XXX
        WHERE  USER_ID = 100
               AND PAYMENT_ID <> 0
    ) x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY JOB_ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle [data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) contains the hours, the minutes, and the seconds as well and your sql client only show the year-month-day part. This difference causes the strange result.
You may use [trunc](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)(service_date) to use only the day parts and keep the data type of the service_date column.

Comment: the data itself only contain date. no hours, minutes and seconds